# adding 2 combobox columns in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am using a datagridview with 2 combobox columns to show account no and description in vb.net 2005.

```
my query = "select acctno, acctdesc from mytable union select ' ','' from mytable" (why union? - so that once user selects acct no, can deselect)
```

I am filling ds1 and ds2 with the query above using dataadapter.

```
dim ds1 as new dataset
cmbcol1.datasource = ds1.tables(0).defaultview
cmbcol1.DisplayMember = "Acctno"
cmbCol1.ValueMember = "Acctno"

-----------------

dim ds2 as new dataset
cmbcol2.datasource = ds2.tables(0).defaultview
cmbcol2.DisplayMember = "Acctdesc"
cmbCol2.ValueMember = "Acctno"

-----------------

My code - 


    Private Sub dgvAcctSelect_EditingControlShowing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles dgvAcctSelect.EditingControlShowing

            Try
                If dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "ACCTNO" Then
                    Dim combo As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                    If combo IsNot Nothing Then
                        RemoveHandler  combo.SelectedIndexChanged,  
                                   AddressOf  combo_SelectedIndexChangedACCT
                        AddHandler  combo.SelectedIndexChanged, 
                                   AddressOfcombo_SelectedIndexChangedACCT
                    End If
                End If

                If dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "ACCTDESC" Then
                    Dim combo As ComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
                    If combo IsNot Nothing Then
                       RemoveHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf 
                               combo_SelectedIndexChangedDESC
                       AddHandler combo.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf 
                               combo_SelectedIndexChangedDESC
                    End If
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

        End Sub

' IF USER SELECTS ACCTNO THEN AUTOMATICALLY CORRESPONDING ACCTDESC should be get selected IN OTHER COLUMN


     Private Sub combo_SelectedIndexChangedACCT(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            Try
                If dgv.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "ACCTCNO" Then
                    Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
                    dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = cb.SelectedValue
                End If
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try

        End Sub



' IF USER SELECTS ACCTDESC THEN AUTOMATICALLY SELECT CORRESPONDING ACCTNO should be get selected IN OTHER COLUMN

    Private Sub combo_SelectedIndexChangedDESC(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Try
            If dgvAcctSelect.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name = "ACCTDESC" Then
                Dim cb As ComboBox = DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)
                dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = cb.SelectedValue
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

    End Sub
```

This is giving Cell value not valid error.

---

If anybody just want to try, just take datagridview with 2 comboboxcolumns. Show any 2 columns like id and desc from any tbale. And try to select id and show desc automatically in othet column. Vice versa

---

```
        Dim cmbCol1 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim ds1 As DataSet
    Dim da1 As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        ds1 = New DataSet
        da1 = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ACCTDESC ,ACCTNO FROM mytable union " & _
        "select ' ' as ACCTNO,'' as ACCTDESC from mytable order by ACCTno", sqlCon)
        ds1.Clear()
        da1.Fill(ds1, "ConnToSqlDrp1")
        If ds1 Is Nothing = False Then
            cmbCol1.DataSource = ds1.Tables("ConnToSqlDrp1").DefaultView
            cmbCol1.DisplayMember = "ACCTno"
            cmbCol1.ValueMember = "SACCTno"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    cmbCol1.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
    cmbCol1.HeaderText = "Account No"
    cmbCol1.Name = "ACCTno"
    cmbCol1.Width = 150
    cmbCol1.AutoComplete = True
    .Add(cmbCol1)

    Dim cmbCol2 As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    Dim ds2 As DataSet
    Dim da2 As Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Try
        ds2 = New DataSet
        da2 = New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ACCTNO,ACCTDESC FROM MYTABLE union " & _
       "select ' ' as ACCTNO,'' as ACCTDESC from MYTABLE order by ACCTDESC", sqlCon)
        ds2.Clear()
        da2.Fill(ds2, "ConnToSqlDrp2")
        If ds2 Is Nothing = False Then
            cmbCol2.DataSource = ds2.Tables("ConnToSqlDrp2").DefaultView
            cmbCol2.DisplayMember = "ACCTDESC"
            cmbCol2.ValueMember = "ACCTNO"
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    cmbCol2.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox
    cmbCol2.HeaderText = "Consol Account Description"
    cmbCol2.Name = "ACCTDESC"
    cmbCol2.Width = 330
    cmbCol2.AutoComplete = True
    'cmbCol2.Visible = False
    .AdDcmbCol2)   



         **THIS IS MY CODE IN FORM LOAD EVENT SO IT SHOULD POPULATE ONLY ONCE.**
```

Answer (score 0):

This could should give you an IndexOutOfBounds Exception. Actually it should give it twice.

```
dim ds1 as new dataset
cmbcol1.datasource = ds1.tables(0).defaultview

dim ds2 as new dataset
cmbcol2.datasource = ds2.tables(0).defaultview
```

when you create a new instance of Data.DataSet the tables property is empty, so without actually filling the dataset, I wonder how does your app not throw an exception? There is no 0th table in the ds1.tables array. If this does not throw you an exception your program's execution logic is flawed. Something does not get called and that something should fill the datasets. Without the datasets filled and attached to the comboboxes those comboboxes will be empty, their SelectedItem is nothing which is why you get a Cell value error. I hope this helps. Check your code.

Comment: Sorry i am filling datasets with the query i have given in my question on top. (With the help of dataadapter) So there is table at 0th position.

Comment: @user1497569 i think we are misunderstanding each other, I see you query, but every time your code passes the New dataset line, your ds1 and ds2 variables get instantialized and initialized, which means that with this empty constructor you are setting them to a basic, empty dataset, which do not have tables. If you have omitted some lines between new dataset and cmbcol.datasource then please post is as well

Comment: Hi Andris. See my latest reply. I couldn't post in this block. i am populating datagridviews in form load event. so it should populate only once.  If have add DataError event Still i can select acctno, it will show desc correctly. If i select desc, it will show acctno correctly. It will catch exception "Cell value not valid" if i clcik few times still it's working. (but this exception keeps on coming)